# Ember: Access name of active child route from parent

Tags: ember.js

I have a pair of routes (parent and child) in EmberJS. I want to bind some attributes in the parent route's template to computed properties that depend on the identity of the active child route. I am aware that the `{{link-to}}` helper automatically sets the `active` class on its element when it matches the current route. However, I want to go beyond this functionality. How can I best get the name of the active child route in the parent controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options. One is to use the [RouterService](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/RouterService/properties/currentRouteName?anchor=currentRouteName) and some computed properties.

There is a method called `currentRouteName` that returns the route as a period separated string.

Another option is to track state in your own Service. Any time that different parts of an app need to share state, a service of some sort is usually the answer.

The Router Service was added in 2.17. This answer applies from then through at least 3.x, and was written as of 3.1.